# Firebase Locally use config variable doesn't work - Error: Missing Plaid "Secret"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, plaid

I am having trouble testing firebase functions locally.
I have ofc some critical api keys I want to protect. So for that I use `functions.config()`.

When launching locally your functions server with `firebase emulators:start` or `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, it shows me an error when the `secret` value is null when using `functions.config().plaid.secret`.

I used `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` to bring my configuration locally. I ran it in my `functions` folder.

The `.runtimeconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "plaid": {
    "secret": "blabla",
    "clientid": "blabla"
  }
}
```

My `index.js` looks like the following:

```
// Using Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Cloud Functions
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// Cloud Firestore
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

// Plaid
const plaid = require("plaid");
const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
    clientID: functions.config().plaid.clientid,
    secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
    env: plaid.environments.development,
});

// Firestore Refs
const usersRef = database.collection("users");

// Token Management
// Create Token
app.post('/get_link_token', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const clientUserId = "SomeUserID";
        // Create the link_token with all of your configurations
        const tokenResponse = await plaidClient.createLinkToken({
            user: {
                client_user_id: clientUserId,
            },
            client_name: 'someproject',
            products: ['auth', 'transactions'],
            country_codes: ['US'],
            language: 'en',
        });
        response.on({ link_token: tokenResponse.link_token });
    } catch (e) {
        // Display error on client
        return response.send({ error: e.message });
    }
});
```

My error is the following:

```
⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
⚠  Error: Missing Plaid "secret"
    at new Client (/Users/somedude/Work/someproject/functions/node_modules/plaid/lib/PlaidClient.js:17:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/somedude/Work/someproject/functions/index.js:18:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:699:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: You have a little bit more context here https://github.com/plaid/plaid-node/issues/345
Still not solved on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, the solution is to actually use what the documentation says.
as of this:

```
const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
    clientID: functions.config().plaid.clientid,
    secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
    env: plaid.environments.development,
});
```

And to be sure you are using at least the version 7.0.0.
For some reason when adding a package with npm, it is installing the 2.1.0 which is absolutely not right.